# Multiple messages received by LocalBroadcast Receiver Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I have read many answers to the problem of receiving the same massage repeatedly by a Broadcast receiver. The solutions is are mostly saying register the receiver in OnResume an unregister in OnPause. This is not possible in my code. I have UI (media player of sorts) and a bound Musicservive.. all is working well except for this multiple message received problem.  When a media file finishes the Musicservice sends a message "Cue Completed" the receiver is getting the message. I then need to determine if the next media needs to directly play or wait for a button press. I can get it to play the next without any problem,  However, if i want it not to play the next piece of music just keeps getting the same messaage and forwards till reaching the end . some code

```
        mp.setOnCompletionListener {


                 if (loop > 0 && loopCount<loop+1) {


                     Toast.makeText(this, "$loopCount of $loop loops", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                     getCurrentsoundPosition()
                     runCue(position)
                     Log.i("loopcount", "$loopCount ")
                     loopCount++

                 }else {
                           if(trigger=="Play-Next" || trigger=="Fade Play-Next"){
                            mpStatus = "cue_completed"
                            sendMediaPlayerStatus()}else
                           {mpStatus="Stopped"
                               sendMediaPlayerStatus()
                           }

                     Log.i("status after completion", mpStatus)
                     loopCount=0
                 }
         }
```

the above is in mymusicservice.

The following is from my UI activity OnCreate

```
    val localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
    localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

            // try {

            Log.i("FullScreenActivity ", "Service got intent with action: ${intent.action} and status mp ${intent.getStringExtra("status")}")

            mpStatus = intent.getStringExtra("status")

            when (mpStatus) {

                "cue_completed" -> {

                    goToNext()
                    tvStatus.clearAnimation()
                    if ( AutoPlayNext == true) {


                        btnPlayCue.callOnClick()
                    }else{

                      myMusicService?.stopCue()
                    }

                }
                "PAUSED" -> tvStatus.text = "PAUSED"
                "IS_PLAYING" -> {tvStatus.text = "PLAYING"
                    updateSeekbar()}
                "Fading Out" -> tvStatus.text = "FADING OUT"
            }




        }

    }, IntentFilter(BoundMusicService.ACTION_MEDIAPLAYER_STATUS))
```

When I run the code this is an example from the logcat

2019-03-04 16:53:43.111 1194-1235/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.ktdevelopement.nigelmccullagh.qsoundkt/com.ktdevelopment.nigelmccullagh.qsoundkt.FullScreenActivity: +225ms
2019-03-04 16:53:46.369 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp IS_PLAYING
2019-03-04 16:53:48.876 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp Fading Out
2019-03-04 16:53:51.791 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp cue_completed
2019-03-04 16:53:52.238 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp IS_PLAYING
2019-03-04 16:53:54.350 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp Fading Out
2019-03-04 16:53:54.490 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp Fading Out
2019-03-04 16:53:55.308 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp Fading Out
2019-03-04 16:53:55.503 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp Fading Out
2019-03-04 16:53:55.986 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp cue_completed
2019-03-04 16:53:56.059 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp cue_completed
2019-03-04 16:53:56.212 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp cue_completed
2019-03-04 16:53:56.245 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp cue_completed
2019-03-04 16:53:56.278 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp Fading Out
2019-03-04 16:53:56.279 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp IS_PLAYING
2019-03-04 16:53:56.281 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp cue_completed
2019-03-04 16:53:56.477 29716-29716/? I/FullScreenActivity: Service got intent with action: Media Player Status and status mp Stopped

Its frustrating me the rest of my app is working fine, but I cannot for the life me sort this out. I have been working on it for 3 days.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really send only one broadcast at a time? Is there any other code that send the same broadcast? If you do not have such code, it's a good idea to use a unique ID for each message.

Answer (score 0):

You were absolutely correct. I was sending the same broadcast more than once. I discovered it inside a runnable designed to fade out the music.